# How to install a python library manually

Tags: python, package, quickfix

I built quickfix engine (http://www.quickfixengine.org/) for one of my tasks and also built in python support for it.

Unfortunately this is a multi user env and I dont have access to the python installation path. Thus the make install command tries to copy over the files and fails. I managed to comment out the two lines where it tries to do that and the make install completed. Since I cannot put the files there, where can I put the *.so* file created?

And how do I let python know that it is there? I looked at python.org documentation but it only describes the process for *setup.py* installations.

Also I tried putting the path for the *.so* in  `sys.path`, that didnt work. And is there any documents about the anatomy of a python package? Thanks.

Comment: "Also I tried putting the path for the .so in sys.path, that didnt work." Have you tried importing the extension module from a script (or interactive session) in the same directory as the `.so` file for the extension?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm going to assume compiling the QuickFix package does not produce a `setup.py` file, but rather only compiles the Python bindings and relies on `make install` to put them in the appropriate place.

In this case, a quick and dirty fix is to compile the QuickFix source, locate the Python extension modules (you indicated on your system these end with a `.so` extension), and add that directory to your `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable e.g., add

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/path/to/python/extensions:PYTHONPATH
```

or similar line in your shell configuration file.

A more robust solution would include making sure to compile with `./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local`. Assuming QuickFix knows to put the Python files in the appropriate `site-packages`, when you do `make install`, it should install the files to `~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`, which, for Python 2.6+, should already be on your Python path as the [per-user site-packages directory](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/).

If, on the other hand, it did provide a `setup.py` file, simply run

```
python setup.py install --user
```

for Python 2.6+.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the official FAQ on installing Python Modules: http://docs.python.org/install/index.html

There are some tips which might help you.

Comment: yes, i had a look at it. But the issue is it describes how to install something that came packaged as a python module (something to be installed by using setup.py). It does not tell you how to install some library that left a .so around. :(

Comment: Here are some other ideas http://dubroy.com/blog/so-you-want-to-install-a-python-package/. Seems like the solution for you might be pip (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).