# Converting library from Python 2.7 to 3.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, converters

I'm writing an equity calculator for poker hands
using this library `Deuces` for hand evaluation
https://github.com/worldveil/deuces

The library is written for Python 2.7 and it can be
installed with the command

```
pip install deuces
```

The library works well in Python 2.7 but I need to
switch to Python 3.4.

I wanted to use `2to3` to convert library files and then
install the library but the command pip doesn't allow this operation

How can I convert the library from Python 2.7 to Python 3.4?

Answer (score 2):

I have published a Python 3 port of Deuces [here](https://github.com/ihendley/treys).

You can also get it via pip:

```
$ pip install treys
```

Answer (score 1):

- Download your library from [deuces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deuces)
- Apply **2to3** to it
- Manually install it [How to install a python library manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933224/how-to-install-a-python-library-manually)

If this doesn't work then nothing would. You probably should rewrite it to python 3 yourself. Yet there could be other libraries used and then you have to rewrite them too.

Comment: I followed exactly what you said with no success: library successfully install itself but at running time function/classes are not detected.

Comment: @F.Noe I wouldn't construe that as no success - you're close than you were. You should double check that you're importing the library from where you think you are - `import deuces; print(deuces.__file__)`